# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

can you see what am I doing wrong here? it is saying:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

```
var zadTwo = 10;
var zadDwa = 5;
var zadZwei = 3;

if (zadTwo > zadDwa && ZadTwo > zadZwei){
    console.log("1 is biggest");
} else if (zadDwa > zadTwo && ZadDwa > zadZwei){
    console.log("2 is biggest");
} else (zadZwei > zadDwa && ZadZwei > zadTwo){
    console.log("3 is biggest");
}
```

Comment: You can’t put a condition after `else`.

Comment: You may want to take a look at some documentation for JavaScript conditions http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/221/conditions#t=201701301757557543116

Answer (score 2):

You don't need conditions on `else` statement as the previous cases were not met, and `else` block code is the last command to perform.

```
} else {
   // all cases were not met, do this instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the missing `if`, you have some typos with the names of the variables.

```js
var zadTwo = 10;
var zadDwa = 5;
var zadZwei = 3;

if (zadTwo > zadDwa && zadTwo > zadZwei) {
//                     ^
    console.log("1 is biggest");
} else if (zadDwa > zadTwo && zadDwa > zadZwei) {
//                            ^
    console.log("2 is biggest");
} else if (zadZwei > zadDwa && zadZwei > zadTwo) {
//     ^^                      ^
    console.log("3 is biggest");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the second else, there is no need of a condition.   Unless its inclusive, that is, unless you don't want anything to occur if this condition is not met as well.  Either way, you cannot have

```
else (condition)
```

you need

```
else if (condition)
```

or just

```
else
```