# Running JavaScript function to gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a personal website and decided to add a "skills div" where the content of the div changes depending on what tab is selected. to do this i have created a function the changes the innerHTML of the div to a string containing all the `<p>`, `<img>` and `<scripts>`'s. this works fine for the paragraphs and images but when i run the function in the script it gives me an error

here is the code that changes the innerHTML (only including the  because it is just a big string with html elements and tags):

```
            var tabContents = ['', '<img src="Skills/3DModelling/Night_Swarz.png" alt="ModelImage1.png" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; height: 200px;">' +
        '<img src="Skills/3DModelling/Night_Swarz_AllClothes.png" alt="ModelImage2.png" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; height: 200px;">' +
        '<p style="position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 50px); left: 0px; width: 170px; text-align: center; font-size: 180%;">Character 1</p>' +
        '<img src="Skills/3DModelling/Samurai_Render.png" alt="ModelImage3.png" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 30px; height: 200px;">' +
        '<img src="Skills/3DModelling/Samurai_Posed.png" alt="ModelImage4.png" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; height: 200px;">' +
        '<p style="position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 50px); right: 0px; width: 170px; text-align: center; font-size: 180%;">Character 2</p>' +
        '<p style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 175px; height: calc(100% - 20px); width: calc(100% - 330px); text-align: center;"> I have been 3D modelling since January of 2014. I have been doing so as a recreational activity in order to provide myself with objects to move around in a gaming environment. I enjoy the coding challanges I face more so than 3D modelling, however through developing my skills I have acquired a talent and satasfaction through the models I have created. I started with very basic designs and now I am confident in my abilities to create models based on 2D sketches, texture and paint the models as well as pose and render them to create images. The tools I have always used are the <i>Blender</i> 3D Modelling program. This is a free program that is mainly used in low budget game making.</p>' +
        '<p style="position: absolute; top: 220px; left: 175px; height: calc(100% - 20px); width: calc(100% - 330px); text-align: center; font-size: 200%;">Some More Models</p>' +         
        '<img id="ChangingImage" style="position: absolute; top: 300px; left: calc(50%); height: 200px;">' +
        '<img src="Images/LeftArrow.png" style="position: absolute; top: 350px; left: calc(50% - 200px); height: 50px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="ChangeToNext("false"");">' +
        '<img src="Images/RightArrow.png" style="position: absolute; top: 350px; right: calc(50% - 200px); height: 50px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="ChangeToNext("true");">' +
        '' +
        '<script>' +
        '' +
        'var currentImage = 0;' +
        'var imageID = ["Night_Swarz.png", "Night_Swarz_AllClothes.png", "Samurai_Posed.png", "Samurai_Render.png"];' +
        '' +
        'function ChangeImageTo(number){' +
            'img = document.getElementById("ChangingImage");' +
            'currentImage = number;' +
            'img.src = "Skills/3DModelling/" + imageID[number];' +
            'img.setAttribute("style", "height: 200px;");' +
            'var width = img.clientWidth/2;' +
            'img.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; top: 300px; left: calc(50% - " + width.toString() + "px); height: 200px;");' +
        '}' +
        '' +
        'function ChangeToNext(forward){' +
            'if(forward == "true"){' +
                'if(currentImage == imageID.length-1){' +
                    'ChangeImageTo(0);' +
                '} else {' +
                    'ChangeImageTo(currentImage+1);' +
                '}' +
            '} else {' +
                'if(currentImage == 0){' +
                    'ChangeImageTo(imageID.length-1);' +
                '} else {' +
                    'ChangeImageTo(currentImage-1);' +
                '}' +
            '}' +
        '}' +
        '' +
        'ChangeImageTo(0);' +
        '</script>','','','',''];
```

function PopulateWithTab(tab){
    div = document.getElementById("SkillsPane");

```
div.innerHTML = tabContents[tab];
```

}

this function is meant to change an image to cycle through a list however once the function is run this message is displayed in the console of the webpage:

```
Index.html:2     Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

this is line 2 in index.html:

```
<html>
```

Comment: `this is line 2 in index.html` - yeah, but that's not the line 2 of the **javascript** in index.html (which is where the error is at) - also, the "string" you've presented in the question results in valid script, so the error isn't in the question, but something you've missed

Comment: *"when i run the function in the script"* - Which function? How do you run it? Including JS as a string like that seems an odd thing to do, but in any case you have not shown relevant parts of that code - isn't the string value being assigned to a variable? Where is the opening `[` of your array? How do you call `PopulateWithTab()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942368/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: okay sorry for not including the whole thing, i didn't realise it would just make it more confusing. i have now edited the question to include all the elements used to populate the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [InnerHtml Security considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations)

Although this may look like a cross-site scripting attack, the result is harmless. HTML5 specifies that a `<script>` tag inserted via innerHTML should not execute.

> Note: script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted.

[InnerHtml wc3/specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0)

## [Conditional (ternary) Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Your `if / else` implementation it's hard to read / debug, use an [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) implementation. 
 ( You probably have an extra `}`)

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

Comment: You should use jquery or follow this simple tutorial: [How to create Tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)

Comment: thank you very much, i'm sorry if this question was a little confusing this is my first question on this site